# Scheme Sum with entered number and term

Tags: lambda, sum, scheme

My first question  :D

I want to write a function which gives me a sum according to an entered number and term.

I have this right now:

```
(define series  (lambda (n a-term)
             (if (= n 0)
                 0
             (+ a-term (series (- n 1) a-term)))))
```

I want to enter a natural number `n` (the sum from 0 to `n`) and I want to enter an `a-term`

such as `(+ n 1)` or `(sqr(n))`. The `a-term` basically says how to calculate whats in the  sum.

I get an error saying that `+: expects a number as 1st argument, given (lambda (a1) ...)`
So basically it expects a-term here :  `(+ a-term (series (- n 1) a-term)))))` to be a number but why isnt it a number? I mean if I enter a number for n why doesnt it return a number for a-term?

a valid call would be `(series 10 (lambda (n) (sqr(n))))` . The result should be the sum of all squarenumbers up to 10  (385).

another example could be `(series 100 (lambda (n) n))`. 
The result would be 5050 = the sum of all numbers from 0 to 100

I hope you can understand my problem and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd call `series` with some arguments and what the expected result is?

Comment: sure!
edited an example in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the procedure `aterm` with `n` as a parameter you need to express it as `(aterm n)`:

```
(define series  
  (lambda (n a-term)
    (if (= n 0)
        0
        (+ (a-term n) (series (- n 1) a-term)))))
```

then

```
> (series 10 (lambda (n) (sqr n)))
385
```

or, shorter

```
> (series 10 sqr)
385
```